# views slideshow force al link to basic page instead of the slideshow's custom made url

Tags: javascript

I am using Views Slideshow for my front page and I want the url output of the image to go to a basic page but there is a conflict because the slideshow creates a page with that image and it makes it a different page than the one it should point to.
Example: I have a slideshow image that should point to the about-us page but when creating the about us image slide it creates a new url...so I end up with one about-us page and the slideshow image points to /node/23.

I tried the image link formatter module, created the proper field in Slideshow (Content type) field_image_custom_link and linked the image to this field. And in views I set a rewrite result to output the field as a link and put [field_image_custom_link] and it will simply send the image to the url: `/field_image_custom_link#overlay-context=!` 
Any help would be appreciated, I just want the slides to point to specific existing pages! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a field to the content type which you are using in your slideshow. Use this field to hold the URL it should point to. Then, add the field in your slideshow view and make it hidden. Now you can use that hidden field to rewrite the URL of the image in the view.

Comment: thanks, now I have this hidden custom link in views but it's not linked to the image, if I make that custom link display then I see the proper link. Here is an image showing the "unhidden" custom link and the link the image points to. http://groovymotion.com/screenshots/views.jpg

Comment: Yes, I think you´re heading the right direction. Now you need to proceed to the last step (in the last sentence) in my answer. In Views you can configure settings per field; one of them is rewrite field output. More info here: https://drupal.org/node/1578524.

Comment: yeah for now I have my image field linked to content and the custom link with a rewrite: Output this field as a link and then link path: [field_image_custom_link]. I tried the opposite and put the rewrite for the image field but this is where it outputs /path/[field_image_custom_link]

Comment: One thing to make sure in your View is that the field you're using as a token for your image link is above the Image field in the _Fields_ section of your View. Otherwise the View can't access the data.

Comment: ok that worked but I still have an issue, the title of the slideshow points to a brand new node and I checked the content type and the custom link is on top of everything and in views fields also. How can the title link to the custom link?

Comment: Can you post some annotated screenshots to clarify?

Comment: I just fixed it, I changed the title settings, unchecked "Link this field to the original piece of content" and set a rewrite output to [field_image_custom_link] :)